# notebook.add() returns bad window path name

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to have a ttk notebook display 2 tabs based on 2 classes, the code is the following :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Dashboard:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, width = 400, height = 400, bg = "red")
        self.frame.pack(expand = True)
class Options :
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, width = 400, height = 400, bg = "blue")
        self.frame.pack(expand = True)
class Tabs:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.master)
        self.options = Options(self.notebook)
        self.dashboard = Dashboard(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.options)
        self.notebook.add(self.dashboard)
        self.notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)


class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.tabs = Tabs(self.master)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = MainGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

However, when I run this I have this error (only happens when I try to use the "add" method of the ttk.Notebook) :`_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name "<__main__.Options object at 0x0000016E51653DC0>"`

I don't understand why my syntax is wrong, can someone help me with that ?
Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child pane widget is usually a `Frame` or a subclass of one. I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but you can get rid of the error (and a similar one for the other class) by deriving both of them from the tkinter `Frame` class like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Dashboard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, width=400, height=400, bg="red")
        self.frame.pack(expand=True)


class Options(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, width=400, height=400, bg="blue")
        self.frame.pack(expand=True)

class Tabs:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.master)
        self.options = Options(self.notebook)
        self.dashboard = Dashboard(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.options)
        self.notebook.add(self.dashboard)
        self.notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)


class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.tabs = Tabs(self.master)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = MainGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. It indeed got rid of the error, but to be honest I had no chance making it work like I wanted to. The idea is to have two tabs "Dashboard" and "Options", each having their own  content. 

The only way I could make it work is to have (for Options) : 
```class Options(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)```

and then use it later in another class. But when I call it, I need to declare it with all size, color... arguments. I'd like to have all arguments declared right away in my "Options" class.

Comment: You can automatically add multiple widgets to class `Options` instances in its `__init__()` method if you wish. Just make sure that first argument passed to *their* constructors is `self` (i.e. the `Frame` being created). For example: `Button(self, text='Something', command=function)` would put the button on the `Options` tab if its made a child of the `Notebook`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I think I get how to do it now :) I marked your answer as accepted.